# M-Pesa payment success

Tags: java

Am doing some automation in my app, need a way to listen to whether payment has been made successfully(customer debited).I do not want to depend on the payload sent to the URL provided. That is, the phone umber provided  receives STKPush to enter the pin, then pin is entered and the customer is debited. Now want to **listen to debit part of it** ,so that when debit is successful I start  an activity in my app .The response below is for STKPush and I do not want to start the activity from there.Kindly assist.

```
mApiClient.mpesaService().sendPush(stkPush).enqueue(new Callback<STKPush>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<STKPush> call, @NonNull Response<STKPush> response) {

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

            try {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    Timber.d("post submitted to API. %s", response.body());
                    
                    RazorpayPaymentSuccess();
                    new Intent(MainACheckout.this, MainActivity_The_Current_providers.class);

                    //Toast.makeText(MainACheckout.this, "Now ready to save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                    Timber.e("Response %s", response.errorBody().string());
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainACheckout.this);
                    ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                    View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.customview, viewGroup, false);
                    builder.setView(dialogView);
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error!");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Something went wrong");
                    alertDialog.show();

                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity_Placing_orders.this, "Not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<STKPush> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Timber.e(t);
        }
    });
```